# How to append temporary value to db value

Tags: php, sql

I have a `city` column in my `cities` table with three rows:

1st row is new-york,
2nd is las-vegas, and
3rd is miami

Here is my non-working code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city='$city".-home-page."'";
```

The ideal output would be:

new-york-home-page, las-vegas-home-page, and miami-home-page

Instead of:

new-york, las-vegas, and miami.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: why not just do it in the php, would be the standard apprach

Comment: i have them set up as pages

such as example.com/new-york or example.com/miami

Comment: Removed the LIMIT 1, didn't mean to have that there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to attach values to your results:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(city, '-home-page') FROM cities
```

> The ideal output would be new-york-home-page, las-vegas-home-page, and miami-home-page

Your `WHERE` doesn't match what you're trying to achieve. If you include:

```
WHERE city='$city"
```

Then you wouldn't match "new-york", "las-vegas", and "miami" because they are different from each other. Likewise, your "LIMIT 1" would only return a single result.

*Note: You haven't specified which version of SQL you're using, but this will work in MySQL (which I'm assuming you're using).*

Comment: It should work with `*,` but if not, you can specify the columns you need. For example, `SELECT city, CONCAT(city, '-home-page') FROM cities` to just retrieve the columns you need.